# Why isn't my UIScrollViewDelegate being called in a swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-playground

I wrote the following playground on the Swift Playgrounds iPad app:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
let view = UIScrollView()
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.contentSize = CGSize(width:100,height:2000)
class Foo : NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("yo")
    }
}
view.delegate = Foo()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

This creates a scroll view, whose scrollbar can be seen if you drag your finger on the view. But the UIScrollViewDelegate method never seems to be called. Why?

Edit: meant to use scrollViewDidScroll and not scrollViewDidScrollToTop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because `delegate` is declared as a `weak` property. Since the code is not keeping a `strong` reference to the `Foo` object any where else, it immediately deallocates it.

When I try to run this in the xcode, it actually gives a warning for this as well.

However, when I keep a strong reference to the delegate, it works.

Comment: I tried saving Foo() in a variable like `let foo = Foo(); view.delegate = foo` and that didn't make a difference. Does that not make a strong reference?

Comment: I'm afraid not. When you assign it to a variable, it's a strong reference, but once the context is over, the reference is reduced as well, and at that point it only has the `weak` delegate reference pointing to it. The way I was able to create a strong reference was by keeping a reference in the `ViewController` (I ran it in an xCode app)

Comment: Looks like that actually does make a strong reference. The reason it seemed to not work was because I accidentally wrote scrollViewDidScrollToTop instead of scrollViewDidScroll, so it didn't do anything when I scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

You should create delegate variable and set to scrollView. Because `delegate` in scrollView is weak type

UPDATE: `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` only call when you tap status bar. If you want track drag of scrollview. Using `scrollViewDidScroll` instead.

```
import UIKit

import PlaygroundSupport
let view = UIScrollView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 700))
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.contentSize = CGSize(width:100,height:2000)
class Foo : NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("yo")
  }
}

let deleate = Foo()
view.delegate = deleate
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: @tbodt I just change `scrollViewDidScrollToTop` to `scrollViewDidScroll`. Delegate work perfect